# How to Set data into spinner using Recycler VIEW

Tags: android, retrofit

In my code i have `RecyclerView`.I am setting id and name into `TextView`.

```
 private List<Listitem> itemList;
 private Context context;


//For Spinner
private String[] items = new String[itemList.size()];
private ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter;


public ListItemAdapter(Context context, List<Listitem> itemList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemList = itemList;
 //   this.items = items;

}











@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // Simple Text Data
    holder.id.setText(itemList.get(position).getProducts_id());
    holder.name.setText(itemList.get(position).getProducts_name());
    holder.description.setText(itemList.get(position).getProducts_description());

  //  holder.price.setText(itemList.get(position).getProducts_regular_price());

    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner, items);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner);
    holder.spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    //      String spinnerPos = spinnerArrayAdapter.getPosition (itemList.get());


    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
 items[i] = itemList.get(position).getProducts_regular_price();
        holder.price.setText(items[i]);
```

I want to set price data into Spinner.I am stuck while getting `NullPointerException`

here in items.please help.

```
 private String[] items = new String[itemList.size()];

public class Listitem {

    @SerializedName("products_id")
    @Expose
    private String products_id;
    @SerializedName("products_name")
    @Expose
    private String products_name;
    @SerializedName("products_description")
    @Expose
    private String products_description;
    @SerializedName("products_regular_price")
    @Expose
    private String products_regular_price;
    //getter and setter
    }
```

How do i get products_regular_price and how do i set into `Spinner`.getting 8 value which is in my json response.
I just want to set data into `Spinner`

```
List<ListItem> itemList
```

Comment: can you show your error msg?

Comment: getting null pointer Exception here                                                                private String[] items = new String[itemList.size()];                                                                    I just want to put Price TextView into Spinner.

Comment: Initialize `items = new String[itemList.size()];` in `ListItemAdapter` constructor after `this.itemList = itemList;`

Comment: @PujaSingh Did u pass _String[]_ in your constructor too ?

Comment: yes i m trying  private String[] items = new String[itemList.size()];
 public ListItemAdapter(Context context, List<Listitem> itemList,String[] str) {
      
       this.items= str;

Comment: No. This is wrong what are you r doing. Read my above comment. Still u have doubt ask me

Comment: As u edited below as itis i put there so it gives exception.So i m trying other but still null pointer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123904/discussion-between-piyush-and-puja-singh).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `itemList.size()` which is yet not initialize, so it can be the reason to get `NullPointerException`

You can do this like this :

```
private List<Listitem> itemList;
private Context context;
//For Spinner

    private String[] items ;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter;


    public ListItemAdapter(Context context, List<Listitem> itemList) {
       this.context = context;
       this.itemList = itemList;
       items = new String[itemList.size()];


    }
```

Try this , Hope it help you.

Comment: Error:(82, 27) error: constructor ListItemAdapter in class ListItemAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,List<Listitem>,String[]
found: Context,List<Listitem>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: U did a mistake so obvious it wiil throw a exception.